# Sharing DOM element objects constants between methods in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I want to share constants between methods in Vue.js to honor DRY: most people here are looking for data sharing in arrays and/or objects, but I just want to store DOM element objects in variables once in the same component. I use `@vue/cli` to build my apps, so exporting them *before* the Vue.js code is harder (you know, I’m new to this framework); I have several nodes envolved in different methods like `submit();`, `reset();`, etc., and I don’t want to call `document.getElementById();` for each every time I need them. Is there a solution to avoid this, maybe in a more Vue.js-way? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found a definitive solution, thanks to all the replies.

Comment: Have you tried using refs?

Comment: @Vivick that’s what I manage to do (I’m still studying how Vue.js works, coming from AngularJS and React)… so, I guess you can confirm it’s the best way to achive the goal: thank you!

Comment: `I just want to store DOM element objects in variables`...this sounds very non-Vue to me. In Vue you don't create and store DOM nodes directly. Maybe you should update you answer with description of  what you are really trying to accomplish...

Comment: @MichalLevý you’re right, that’s why I asked. Now `$refs` seem more reasonable to me: basically, I’m creating a simple form which does HTTP requests and populate a page nodes with the response. Once the user send another request, all of them should be cleaned and updated, then I have several DOM element objects involved and I’m trying to reduce the initial code.

Comment: @FedericoMoretti What you describe sounds like something very easy in Vue without DOM manipulation  or even `refs` really....

Comment: So, I can achieve the same in a lighter way with just `data`… I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them as `data` props and then reuse them.

```js
data() {
   return {
        elem: null
   };
},
mounted() {
    this.elem = document.getElementById('someId');
},
methods: {
   method1() {
       console.log(this.elem);
   },
   method2() {
       console.log(this.elem);
   }
}
```

I should also mention that Vue has a built in tool for this called `$refs`.

For example:

```html
<template>
  <h1 ref="title">Title</h1>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       someMethod() {
          console.log(this.$refs.title); // h1 element
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I’m currently trying with `refs` and it works as expected, but now I’m wondering if there are some limits: I mean, both `data` and `props` seem to be reusable by imported sub-components just like they use to be in React, while `$ref` doesn’t… if I’m not wrong. I started using Vue.js for the first time some days ago, so I’m still reading the official documentation to understand how it works.

Comment: You can pass `refs` to child components as props: `<SubComponent :title="$refs.title" />`

Answer (score 0):

First of, thank you all for your kind answers. I decided to proceed assigning values to the `data` object – instead of mapping DOM element objects in `$refs` – with an exception for nodes I need to manipulate with CSS (some regions of my project should be shown/hidden on user input): it works really faster!